# Redirecting full URL including directories

Tags: redirect, http-redirect

I'm migrating to a new website.

I want to be able to redirect everything from the old website to the new website in the following structure.

**Example 1:**

http://dev.website-old.com/abc/123

to

http://dev.website-new.com/abc/123

**Example 2:**

http://dev.website-old.com/abc/123/xyz

to

http://dev.website-new.com/abc/123/xyz

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This rewrite redirect all requests (1:1) from dev.website-old.com to dev.website-new.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dev\.website-old\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://dev.website-new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```